# Azure DevOps YAML Parallel Runs Not Queueing

Tags: azure-devops

Something I've noticed, is that given a multistage yaml pipeline, I can kick off two simultaneous runs by completing two pull requests in quick succession. I then have two runs, each executing the same stage at the same time.

Luckily I've not hit any errors on mine, but what I want to see is or don't know how to do, is set it to queue up whole runs so I won't have both attempting to deploy at the same time, or to have it only run one stage for a given run at a time, so the later run would effectively block until a given stage becomes free again.

I can't find any details about this within the docs. The docs only seem to talk about stages depending on each other within the same run, not entirely different runs.

Comment: Just want to confirm whether specifying the agent name in pipeline can help you avoid the YAML parallel run? If not or has any confusing about it, free to comment below:-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your described, it seems you has enough concurrency to support its parallel. Just not sure here you were running in Hosted agent or Private agent.

If your multi-stage pipeline ran with Hosted agent, you can [change the project to private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#microsoft-hosted-cicd) to limit the parallel number to 1. Because as default, only public project has 10 Hosted agent parallel usage.

Oppositely, if you were running with private agent pool. You can add `demand` to `pool`.

With [`demand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manually-entered-demands), such as `Agent.Name -equals {agent name}`, job will only run on a certain agent rather than picking up others. In this way, no matter how many builds are triggered, it will not work in parallel at the same time as the current machine is occupied by the other job. It can only run until the current agent is released. This could help to reach What you want.